# Why does heavy water have two different solvent peaks with DSS and TSP?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I was going through the [NMR solvent peaks chart of Cambridge isotope laboratories (PDF)](http://isotope.com/uploads/File/new_datachart.pdf) and I noticed that $\ce{D2O}$ had two solvent peaks: one at 4.8 with sodium trimethylsilylpropanesulfonate (DSS) and one at 4.81 with trimethylsilylpropanoic acid (TSP).

Why do we not see two peaks for other solvents as well? Is it necessary to use an internal reference with $\ce{D2O}$ and why can we not just reference the $\ce{HOD}$ peak?

Comment: As you know "D2O" will not show a signal in proton NMR. Something else must be generating this signal. In the footnote of the solvent chart it reads "When the exchange rate between H2O and HDO is slow on the NMR timescale the water peak appears as two peaks"

Comment: I don't think there are two peaks being observed, I think it's more like the chemical shift is changed a bit depending on what internal standard is used

Comment: @orthocresol I agree with you that we get peaks at different positions based on the internal standard that we use. I was curious as to why we don't see this phenomena with other solvents. Suppose we were to add a slight amount of TSP or DSS to other solvents would they show different chemical shifts?

Comment: @AChem that was my second question. If we take $CDCl_3$ for example it will also not show a peak but because of proton deuterium exchange some of the $CDCl_3$ becomes $CHCl_3$. The same should occur for deuterium as well. We should see a HOD peak or a $H_2O$ peak. Why can't we just reference that peak and not use an internal reference? However when I look at literature they seem to use an internal reference only when performing $D_2O$ nmr.

Comment: @carbon12, Yes you are right that the NMR signal can arise only *after* isotope exchange but not from CDCl3. D2O also exchanges protons very fast with labile protons in alcohols or carboxylic acids... recall the term D2O shake. H2O should always be present in all solvents until and unless they are bone dry. I don't know the signal strength ratio of D2O vs. H2O (adventitious water). For  peak referencing question, orthocresol is the NMR expert.